# Epochs for new batch when online training?

Tags: rnn, mini-batch-gradient-descent, online-learning, epochs

I am online training a RNN with fixed batch size *k* on a time series. Initially I train my model with *n* batches and a number of *e* epochs. When a new batch *n+1* is available, I would like to update the weights, rather than retrain the model with all *n+1* batches.
**My question is, should I train the model on the new batch with the same number of epochs *e*? Should the number of epochs effectively be *1*? Is there any way to know what optimal number to choose?**
Obviously, the more epochs I use on the new batch, the more weight this new batch will have on my predictions.
I would like to read more on this, so if anyone has references they are very welcome!